# What happened to my meshes?

Tags: mesh

I'm pretty new to Blender so I don't know if this is my stupidity or something else. I realized that my icon for meshes changed and I can't access them. I don't know if its something I did because every model I try to work with has the same problem. Sorry if this is a really simple problem but I really need to know.

How my mesh icon looks now>
[image]

How the icon used to look>
[image]

Comment: Please show us the complete screenshot of the outline panel. I believe that you have not lost your mesh data but instead, looking at something totally different.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you are looking at the **material data-blocks** (i.e. the first image you have put it up here) instead of the **object data-blocks**.

Look out for **Blender File** as a **Display Mod**e on your *Outliner*. You should have all the data displayed that is present on your current Scene.

[image]